# Issue with JSON.parse , don't know why is not parsing everything

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js, transloadit

I'm developing a web app with **Node.js** using **Sails framework**(based on Express) and i'm using a third party image solution called Transloadit (no need to know Transloadit).

Anyway, that's not the problem, i'm been able to implement the Transloadit form and receive the information from their API.

My problem is that, Transloadit gives me the response as a String, and I need to access the response objects, so i'm using `var objRes = JSON.parse(req.body.transloadit);` to parse it to an JSON object, and when I `console.log(objRes);` the object is not correctly parsed, i get this: (see all JSON here https://gist.github.com/kevinblanco/9631085 )

```
{
    a bunch of fields here ..... 
    last_seq: 2,
    results: {
        thumb: [
            [
                Object
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

And I need the data from the **`thumb`** array, my question is, **Why is doing that when parsing ?**

Here's the entire request `req.body` object: https://gist.github.com/kevinblanco/9628156 as you can see the `transloadit` field is a string, and I need the data from some of their fields.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the parsing of the JSON -- in fact there is no problem at all.

consol.log limits the depth of what it is printing which is why you are seeing [object] in the output.

If you want to see the full output in node.js then just use the inspect utility like this;

> console.log(util.inspect( yourobject, {depth:null} ));

and that will print the entire content.

Note that this is just an artifact of console.log printing it.

Comment: I didn't knew that, thank you very much that fix it, I can see the entire object tree now.